# How to link to Delete Verb in Ruby-on-rails template without using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My question is how to tell rails that it should be DELETE request and not GET. It is easy with link_to helper , but how to do this in this situation, as I need this link in given format.

Any suggestions ?

```
      <a class="item" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Like" href="<%=  logout_path %>">
        <i class="fi-power"></i>
        <label id='itemlabel2'>Logout</label>
      </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So naturally, whenever one wants to send a delete request via the link in Rails, it normally would be done like this...

`<%= link_to "Delete", @object_name, method: :delete %>`

If we then have a look at what happens inside the browser, we will see the following...

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/object_name/1">Delete</a>
```

As you can see the key ingredient here is `data-method="delete"`, which initiates a `POST` request. Hence, my suggestion would be to convert your code to this...

```
<a class="item" role="button" tabindex="0" data-method="delete" aria-label="Like" href="/logout">
  <i class="fi-power"></i>
  <label id='itemlabel2'>Logout</label>
</a>
```

Hopefully this might help you out.

**UPDATE:**

Note that I have used `href="/logout"` above. I forgot to mention that this implies that inside of your **routes.rb** file you have to have a correct **named route** specified to that action, which in this case would be...

`delete     'logout'    => 'sessions#destroy'`

...which in turn would trigger the destroy action inside of the SessionsController.